# Improve efficiency of modules

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, big-o, performance

I am running the loop in this method for around 1 million times but it is taking a lot of time maybe due O(n^2) , so is there any way to improve these two modules :-

```
def genIndexList(length,ID):
   indexInfoList = []
   id = list(str(ID))
   for i in range(length):
       i3 = (str(decimalToBase3(i)))
       while len(i3) != 12:
           i3 = '0' + i3
       p = (int(str(ID)[0]) + int(i3[0]) + int(i3[2]) + int(i3[4]) + int(i3[6]) +     int(i3[8]) + int(i3[10]))%3
       indexInfoList.append(str(ID)+i3+str(p))
   return indexInfoList
```

and here is the method for to convert number to base3 :-

```
def decimalToBase3(num):
   i = 0
   if num != 0 and num != 1 and num != 2:
       number = ""
       while num != 0 :
           remainder = num % 3 
           num = num / 3 
           number = str(remainder) + number
       return int(number)
   else:
       return num
```

I am using python to make a software and these 2 functions are a part of it.Please suggest why these 2 methods are so slow and how to improve efficiency of these methods.

Comment: I can see a few improvements, yes, but what is the intended input and output?

Comment: first the getIndexList method is called wherein I supply length of some huge list as argument and ID is any 2 digit number and I return a new list whose items are appended with the original list whose length is supplied.Basically some details are added to original list.

Comment: Why not pass in the list itself?

Comment: Its of no use say if I passed the list then what ? every time I need to append items to list which I think is not efficient.

Comment: Do you really need the result to be a list? maybe you could return a generator instead. Since the list is huge, the slow performance might come from memory allocation. Returning generator will help.

Comment: Ohh yes changed that thanks ..coming back to point how to improve efficiency of loop ?

Comment: About the efficiency of the loop, you could try incrementing an array representation of base 3 number directly instead of incrementing the base 2 representation and converting them every time. Well, in fact, why not increment the **string** representation directly.

Comment: @Billiska and what about big0 its still of the order n^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function can be reduced to:

```
def genIndexList(length, ID):
   indexInfoList = []
   id0 = str(ID)[0]
   for i in xrange(length):
       i3 = format(decimalToBase3(i), '012d')
       p = sum(map(int, id0 + i3[::2])) % 3
       indexInfoList.append('{}{}{}'.format(ID, i3, p))
   return indexInfoList
```

You may want to make it a generator instead:

```
def genIndexList(length, ID):
   id0 = str(ID)[0]
   for i in xrange(length):
       i3 = format(decimalToBase3(i), '012d')
       p = sum(map(int, id0 + i3[::2])) % 3
       yield '{}{}{}'.format(ID, i3, p)
```

The second function could be:

```
def decimalToBase3(num):
   if 0 <= num < 3: return num
   result = ""
   while num:
       num, digit = divmod(num, 3) 
       result = str(digit) + result
   return int(result)
```

Next step; you are just generating a sequence of base-3 digits. Just generate these directly:

```
from itertools import product, imap
def base3sequence(l=12, digits='012'):
    return imap(''.join, product(digits, repeat=l))
```

This produces base3 values, 0-padded to 12 digits:

```
>>> gen = base3sequence()
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print next(gen)
... 
000000000000
000000000001
000000000002
000000000010
000000000011
000000000012
000000000020
000000000021
000000000022
000000000100
```

and `genIndexList()` becomes:

```
from itertools import islice
def genIndexList(length, ID):
   id0 = str(ID)[0]
   for i3 in islice(base3sequence(), length):
       p = sum(map(int, id0 + i3[::2])) % 3
       yield '{}{}{}'.format(ID, i3, p)
```

Comment: So what does this first function now returns it doesn't look like a list .. Its not mandatory for me to get list all I need is data as some array from where I could get it back and append it to original list for corresponding index

Comment: @hitman_93: `original_list.extend(genIndexList(len(original_list), someid))` will do that.

Comment: And what does format and map does they are giving me error
    p = sum(map(int, [id[0]] + i3[::2])) % 3
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: @hitman_93: sorry, of course, `i3` is a string, not a list, so we can just prepend `id[0]`.

Comment: @hitman_93: The `[::2]` takes every second digit of `i3`. The `map()` turns the first digit of `ID` plus every second digit of `i3` into integers, `sum()` adds them all up.

Comment: @Martjin and what about order its still order of n^2 ?

Comment: Generator does not iterate over 700 k it gives error stopIteration

Comment: @hitman_93: if your code goes anywhere past 531440 (largest 12 digit base-3 number) you have a problem with your old code, because then it starts generating more 13 or more digits. What do you want to happen in that case? I suspect that would be a bug, as you start ignoring the digits beyond the first 12.

Comment: Ohh yes thats precisely the reason why my code was going on for ever its was running an infinite loop for those number whose base3 strings where greater than 12 since i wrote while len(i3) != 12 ... Thanks a lot @Martjin you hit the bulls eye